# Java application to login from database

Tags: java, swing, awt

Hey I made a login page which access the database for correct credentials and then accepts the user.
Suppose there are 3 users who can login and each user has a different table in database, so how would I display frame of only that user.
This is the code i used for login button

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logindb" ,"root","");
            String sql = "Select * from login where username=? and password=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username.getText());
            pst.setString(2, password.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                newwindow field = new newwindow();
                field.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
                }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "InValid User");
                username.setText("");
                password.setText("");
            }
            con.close();


    }                                        
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

How should the condition be placed?

Comment: You need to process the data, returned in the `ResultSet`: you should have some `User` object who can have set of roles/permissions which you setup after successful login - then you pass this instance of `User` to your window or whatever

Comment: *each user has a different table in database* Your current code just validates if the user exists. So, if yes, then you need to invoke another SQL query to get the data from that users specific table. How you do that is up to you because we don't know how your database is designed.

Comment: And please try to decompose your code and use different classes to encapsulate entities (data model), access to database, and UI - it is a _very_ bad practice to put all these things into simple handler of button click.  Good luck!